# Give the formula of a SVM with R

Tags: r, svm

I use this code for my SVM prediction

```
library(gdata)
data = read.csv2("test.csv")
data


library(e1071)
model <- svm(cote ~ .,data,kernel='radial')

#model1 <- svm(y ~ x1+x2, data=f, type='nu-classification',kernel='radial',tolerance=0.001,gamma=2.5,cost=2,nu=0.8,cross=10,shrinking=FALSE)

predict(model, subset(data, select = - c(cote)))
```

Now I need to take the literal formula of this SVM to paste it on a C++ program. How can I do that ?

Thx

Comment: What does the C++ program do? It is not clear how you want to use the "literal formula" in the C++ program. Please be more clear and show what you tried.

Comment: `predict.svm`'s help page does not suggest that it should return a result that has the formula. Even looking at the model object suggests that the formula was not retained. Why don't you take one or two steps back and describe the project and goals of this effort?

Comment: This appears to be duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26293/how-to-obtain-decision-boundaries-from-linear-svm-in-r.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the formula can be recovered from the 'model'-object. Try this:

```
  model$call[[2]]
```

Example:

```
> ?e1071::predict.svm
> model <- svm(Species ~ ., data = iris)

> model$call[[2]]
# Species ~ .
```

If you want that as a character variable the usual methods of coercion work as expected.